# Ubuntu Server 12.0.4 vsftpd timeout using external IP

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, port-forwarding, vsftpd

I am having a problem connecting to my Ubuntu 12.0.4 server with vsftpd using my external IP. Connecting with local IP is successful. I am using FileZilla for the ftp client. I know there is a bunch of stuff online about this but nothing has fixed my problem. I have port 21 forwarded in my router, the vsftpd.conf file is correct I believe. The only thing I can think is that I don't have any passive configurations set, but not sure if I need them. If somebody could please help me with this that would be great. I can provide my vsftpd.conf if needed, and also I can take screenshots of my router config to make sure that is correct also.

Comment: "I know there is a bunch of stuff online about this but nothing has fixed my problem." - it is not clear from this what you tried. So how should we know which of the offered solution don't fix your problem.

Comment: I've tried changing my vsftpd.conf to a bunch of different configurations except adding passive arguments. Thats all I have tried

Comment: I wish you much luck getting a useful response with providing practically no useful information.